# PHP form submission with echo html post's empty array

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm using php to dynamically create multiple buttons on my web page that have increasing values 01 to 09. When I create the forms as below the buttons are created as expected with the correct values but when I submit the form an empty array is posted.

The code here is inside a for loop that increments $i:

```html
echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="RunSmokeTest" value="0'.$i.'">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run Test">';
echo '</form>';
```

Here is the HTML that is created:

[image]

However, when I change the code to take out the $i variable, the form will be submitted as expected but all the buttons will have the same value which I can't have.

Here is the start of test.php that prints out array(0) { } when I click the submit button and an alert comes up with message 'empty'.

```html
var_dump($_POST);

if(empty($_POST['RunSmokeTest']))
{
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("empty")';
  echo '</script>';
}
else{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Where you have `name` attr for button? And what kind of array are you expecting off?

Comment: so, you create 9 forms that all have the same action?

Comment: I've just checked that adding a name to the submit button is still giving the same problem. The forms essentially do the same thing but in test.php i check if value = 01 do this, else if value=02 do something else etc.

Comment: _"but in test.php i check if value = 01 do this, else if value=02 do something else etc."_ - well then you need to show us that part, so that we can see if you did anything wrong there.

Comment: I've added a section from test.php but it doesn't really get past the check if POST is empty @CBroe

Comment: If you get `array(0) { }`, it means your script has not received any POST parameters. Check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to verify if it was even called via POST at all.

Comment: Perfect that got it thanks. The request_method was Get. Do you know why it was GET when I have used POST in the form? @CBroe

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser development tools, and watch what happens when you submit the form - likely there's a redirect there, that makes the browser issue a second request, using method GET this time. See if you have any such rewriting configured yourself, and if not if the file name is actually spelled a 100% correct (some auto-correction mechanism on the server might cause a redirect in such a case as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['RunSmokeTest'];
}
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="RunSmokeTest" value="0'.$i.'">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run Test">';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

[Demo is here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jxug-83rb)

Comment: I've tried this but didn't notice any change. What should I expect to happen here?

Comment: You have to give a name of submit button and check if a file is submitted then a print value of a hidden field.@Student101

Comment: Did you see my demo?WHat's the problem?@Student101

Comment: yes your demo prints out the value of each button but my code still posts an empty array for some reason @Nidhi

Comment: copy my code paste in another page and compare it with your code..Your task is very easy...@Student101